# Referencing a Variable with a Param Name and Value (Php and Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, apache

I been trying to pull a value from a Param Name that is loaded by a Js.

The php is what pulling it.

Any advice would be taken gracefully.

I want `$movie` to become the `value` from the

`<param name="movie"   value="http://www.youtube.com..."`

In other words

```
value="http://www.youtube.com..."`
```

Needs to go into `$movie`

I have tried to "include("Api_PlusLoad.js")
But still no luck

Php Code:

```
<?php

    $movie=$_POST['movie'];

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","student");

    mysql_select_db("tvid", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO tv (userid, favorites) VALUES ('2', '$movie');";

    mysql_query( $sql, $con ) or trigger_error( mysql_error( $con ), E_USER_ERROR );

    echo"";

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The Param

```
<object width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie"             value="http://www.youtube.com/v/FavUpD_IjVY&hl=en_GB&feature=player_embedded&version=3">        </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed  src="http://www.youtube.com/v/FavUpD_IjVY&hl=en_GB&feature=player_embedded&version=3"     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always"     width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```

Major problem I am facing is that I want to add the value of the Param Name Movie.
which is below.

I want it to take `value` (beside it) and add to a database which is defined in the PHP.

`$movie` is the variable that references the 'movie' variable which is the Param Name.

With the code I currently have, all it does is insert a blank into the database.

Comment: I didn't get what your problem is, can you explain please?

Comment: updated it check bottom of it

Comment: still didn't really get you , can you re-write the question?
You want to add the value of the Param Name movie to where?
The "Value" of what ? Please make it easier and simple to understand.

Comment: are you trying to submit an object to the PHP script with post? Why not try using a hidden input type with the name movie and the value that you need and submit it instead and then it should pass the right value

Comment: Maybe you could try jquery (javascript framework) and retrieve the value with $('param[name=movie]').val() or $('param').each({here search for movie})

Comment: I have rewritten the question (mainly towards the top) so check the changes there and see if the question is much clearer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sourcestring='<object width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/FavUpD_IjVY&hl=en_GB&feature=player_embedded&version=3">        </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed  src="http://www.youtube.com/v/FavUpD_IjVY&hl=en_GB&feature=player_embedded&version=3"     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always"     width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>';

preg_match_all('/<param name="movie" value="(.*)">/',$sourcestring,$matches);

echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

If i understood you right this should help you to find the solution.

Comment: I have read up on preg_match_all and see it stores the string into a array, So am I able to call the stored info from the array and save to a database?

Comment: right, take a look at the contents of `$matches` in my example